# Multi-color gradient does not show all colors

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient

I have a multicolor gradient it consists of 14 colors. Here is my code:

```
panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
panel1.Refresh();

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 200),0, false);
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend cb = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend();
    cb.Positions = new[] { 0, 1 /15f, 2 / 15f, 3 / 15f, 4 / 15f, 5 / 15f, 6 / 15f, 7 / 15f, 8 / 15f, 9 / 15f, 10 / 15f, 11 / 15f, 12 / 15f, 13 / 15f,1 };

    cb.Colors = new[] {
        Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 50),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 10, 10, 100),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 100),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 70, 70,200),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 255),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 170, 170, 255),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 55, 151, 107),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 117, 194, 103),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 230, 230, 128),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 157, 75),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 185, 154, 100),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 220, 220, 220),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255),
        Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 200) };

    br.InterpolationColors = cb;
    // rotate
    br.RotateTransform(90);
    // paint
    g.FillRectangle(br, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Unfortunately it does not show all the colors. My rectangle's height is 100 but it shows a gradient like this:

[image: Picture of gradient]

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fill the Rectangle Vertical, you should specify the Rotation in the constructor of your `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, colorFrom, colorTo, 90, false);
                                                           Here --^
```

And remove the Transformation

```
br.RotateTransform(90);
```

Since the width and height of the `ClientRectangle` are basically swapped by your current implementation (because of the 90° rotation), you either see only a small part of the gradient or the entire gradient multiple times.

This also doesn't work because you use the wrong `ClientRectangle`. You are using `this.ClientRectangle` in your Form's code-behind. Replace every `this.ClientRectangle` with `panel1.ClientRectangle`.

How this should look:

[image]

How your unmodified code looked:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I did as you said but nothing changed, the problem is with colors, I have a range of colors like green which is not shown in this gradient

Comment: *Nothing* changed? Did you remove the transformation?

Comment: Yes I removed `RotateTransform` and added `90` in constructor

Comment: @MajidHojati This is why the **complete** part in [mcve] is important: You had one more mistake that wasn't obvious without all your code - you are using the wrong ClientRectangle (see updated answer). The code you have would work if it was placed in the `OnPaint` override of a control, but not in your Form's code behind.

Comment: Thanks very much it is fixed now.